# Change nativescript theme with nativescript-themes plugin in app launch

Tags: nativescript

How can I change the NativeScript app theme during the app launch using the [nativescript-themes](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-themes) plugin?

#### JS

```
import application = require("application");

let themes = require("nativescript-themes");

themes.applyTheme('dark-theme.css');

// TODO: Check if user is logged in

application.start({ moduleName: "views/signin/signin" });
```

This isn't working, and yes, this is TS but the transpiled JS doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the proper code is:

```
import application = require("application");
let themes = require("nativescript-themes");

application.cssFile = themes.getAppliedTheme('dark-theme.css');

application.start({ moduleName: "views/signin/signin" });
```

The theming system replaces the currently running "app.css"; so you no longer are using the default "app.css".   If you need app.css still; then you just import into your theme.css files using the @import statement.

Please note; the 'dark-theme.css' that you are using in getAppliedTheme('dark-theme.css') is the **default** theme, if the theme has been changed/chosen by the user in the app and the app is starting up again, then it will use the actual chosen theme, not the default theme.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme using the *

```js
import { Theme } from "@nativescript/theme";

@Component({
    selector: 'ns-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    Theme.setMode(Theme.Light);
  }
  
}
```

- plugin then make changes in the main *app.component.ts* file as per the below code.

You can also change the mode by putting conditions in the ngOnInit lifecycle.